# Batch create files with name and content based on input file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am a mac OS user trying to batch create a bunch of files. I have a text file with column of several hundred terms/subjects, eg:

```
hydrogen
oxygen
nitrogen
carbon
etcetera
```

I want to programmatically fill a directory with text files generated from this subject list. For example, "hydrogen.txt" and "oxygen.txt" and so on, with each file created by iterating through the lines of my list_of_names.txt file. Some lines are one word, but other lines are two or three words (eg: "carbon monoxide"). This I have figured out how to do:

```
awk 'NF>0' list_of_names.txt | while read line; do touch "${line}.txt"; done
```

Additionally I need to create two lines of content within each of these files, and the content is both static and dynamic...

```
# filename
#elements/filename
```

...where in the example above the pound sign ("#") and "elements/" would be the same in all of the files created, but "filename" would be variable (eg: "hydrogen" for "hydrogen.txt" and "oxygen" for "oxygen.txt" etc). One further wrinkle is that if any spaces appear at all on the second line of content, there needs to be a trailing pound sign. For example:

```
# filename
#elements/carbon monoxide#
```

...although this last part is not a dealbreaker and I can use grep to modify list_of_names.txt such that phrases like "carbon monoxide" become "carbon_monoxide" and just deal with the repercussions of this later. (But if it is easy to preserve the spaces, I would prefer that.)

After a couple hours of searching and attempts to use sed, awk, and so on I am stuck at a directory full of files with the correct filename.txt format, but I can't get further that this. Mostly I think my efforts are failing because the solutions I can find for doing something like this are using commands I am not familiar with and they are structured for GNU and don't execute correctly in Terminal on Mac OS.

I am amenable to processing this in multiple steps (ie make all of the files.txt first, then run a second step to populate the content of the files), or as a single command that makes the files and all of their content simultaneously ('simultaneously' from a human timescale).

My horrible pseudocode (IN CAPS) for how this would look as 2 steps:

```
awk 'NF>0' list_of_names.txt | while read line; do touch "${line}.txt"; done
awk 'NF>0' list_of_names.txt | while read line; OPEN "${line}.txt" AND PRINT "# ${line}\n#elements/${line}"; IF ${line} CONTAINS CHARACTER " " PRINT "#"; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple Bash loop and create the files in one shot:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r name; do                       # loop through input file content
  [[ $name ]] || continue                    # skip empty lines
  output=("# $name")                         # initialize the array with first element
  trailing=
  [[ $name = *" "* ]] && trailing="#"        # name has spaces in it
  output+=("#elements/$name$trailing")       # name doesn't have a space
  printf '%s\n' "${output[@]}" > "$name.txt" # write array content to the output file
done < list_of_names.txt
```

Doing it in awk:

```
awk '
    NF { 
          trailing = (/ / ? "#" : "")
          out=$0".txt"
          printf("# %s\n#elements/%s%s\n", $0, $0, trailing) > out
          close(out)
       }
    ' list_of_names.txt
```

Comment: Rather than `/^[[:space:]]*$/ { next } { do stuff` you could just write it briefer as `NF { do stuff`.

Comment: @EdMorton: thanks for your comments.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the whole job in awk will yield better performance than in bash, which [isn't really suited to processing text like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

It seems to me that this should cover the requirements you've specified:

```
awk '
  {
    out=$0 ".txt"
    printf "# %s\n#elements/%s%s\n", $0, $0, (/ / ? "#" : "") >> out
    close(out)
  }
' list_of_subjects.txt
```

Though you could shrink it to a one-liner:

```
awk '{printf "# %s\n# elements/%s%s\n",$0,$0,(/ /?"#":"")>($0".txt");close($0".txt")}' list_of_subjects.txt
```

Comment: Great.  You may want to skip blank / empty lines.

Comment: Since the OP is not using GNU awk - that will fail with a "too many open files" error once you hit about 20 unique input lines (output files). You need to close() the output files as they change and then use `>>` instead of `>` if they can occur again later.

Comment: @EdMorton, right you are, thanks for the reminder. Fixed.